# Python bigram - foreign script

Tags: python, nltk, arabic

I am finding a list of bigrams using Python that include foreign text: Arabic, Russian, Farsi

The results show as such: ('\xd9\x85\xd9\x86\xd8\xa7\xd8\xb8\xd8\xb1\xd9\x87', '\xd9\x85\xd9\x88\xd8\xb3\xd9\x88\xdb\x8c')

What is this script called and how can I convert it to its Arabic/Russian/Farsi counterpart.

I am running this on the terminal in MAC OS using NLTK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bytestring containing utf-8 encoded text:

```
In [5]: '\xd9\x85\xd9\x86\xd8\xa7\xd8\xb8\xd8\xb1\xd9\x87'.decode('utf-8')
Out[5]: u'\u0645\u0646\u0627\u0638\u0631\u0647'

In [6]: print '\xd9\x85\xd9\x86\xd8\xa7\xd8\xb8\xd8\xb1\xd9\x87'.decode('utf-8')         
مناظره
```

Comment: I found this: http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html to be a good  guide to unicode.